# C++ TCP Server (Winsock) Connecting (invalid client) Instantly Then Closes

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, server, winsock2

Edit: Working on a solution - turns out googling 204.204.204.204 gets me further than more descriptive requests.

Honestly. Wits end. I have no idea how I can spend an entire day doing something that took 10 minutes in Flask (Server) and Javascript (client). I need this to run in C++ and allow a client to connect via BlueStacks' port on the same machine. The client is unimportant because I can't even get that far.

I've tried WinSocks, I've tried WxWidget's networking implementation, I've even tried some random C++ wrapper thing. All of them failed (typically within the EXAMPLE! As in, copy paste and errors everywhere). So I ultimately went back to WinSockets and followed a tutorial on YouTube.

```
int ServerStuff() {
WSADATA WsData;
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

int wsOK = WSAStartup(ver, &WsData);
if (wsOK != 0) {
    wxLogMessage("Can't initialize Winsock! Quitting");
    return false;
}

//Create a socket
SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    wxLogMessage("Can't create a socket! Quitting");
    return false;
}

//Bind the ip and port to a socket
sockaddr_in hint;
hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Could also use inet_pton

bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

//Tell winsock the socket is for listening
listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

//Wait for a connection
sockaddr_in client;
int clientSize = sizeof(client);

SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
//if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
//  wxLogMessage("Client Invalid Socket");
//  return false;
//}

char host[NI_MAXHOST];  //Client's remote name
char service[NI_MAXHOST]; //Service (port) the client is connected on

ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST);

if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0) {
    wxLogMessage("Can't initialize Winsock! Quitting");
}
else {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
    wxLogMessage(host);
    int wut = client.sin_port;
    wxString mystring = wxString::Format(wxT("%i"), wut);
    wxLogMessage("Connected on port");
    wxLogMessage(mystring);
    //wxLogMessage(to_string(ntohs(client.sin_port)));
}
wxLogMessage("Got this far somehow");
//Close listening socket - we don't need it anymore - later on we'll learn how to accept multiple client
closesocket(listening);

//while loop: accept and echo message back to client
char buf[4096];

while (true)
{
    ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);

    //Wait for client to send data
    int bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, 4096, 0);

    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        //wxLogMessage("ERROR in recv");
        break;
    }

    if (bytesReceived == 0) {
        wxLogMessage("Client Disconnected");
        break;
    }

    //Echo back to client
    send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived + 1, 0);

    //Close the socket
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    //Cleanup winsock
    WSACleanup();
    wxLogMessage("Welp");
}
}

// event handlers

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
// true is to force the frame to close

ServerStuff();
//Close(true);
}
```

On the YouTube video ("Creating a TCP Server in C++" - not allowed to post links) this works! The command window opens, is blank infinitely until he connects a client and then the client sends a message and the server replies with the same exact message in return.

Not mine. Mine just rushes through everything and then closes. My log used to immediately quit on the commented code where it states the client socket is invalid so I commented it out. Now my output is:
204.204.204.204
Connected on port
52428
Got this far somehow

I don't know what to do. I'm just trying to send data over a same-machine TCP connection. I'm baffled as to how this is so difficult. It seems like some random process is immediately trying to connect as a client to my server ? But why is it allowed to connect on port 52428 when I'm explicitly hosting on 54000?

My goal:
Start Server
Connect to Server using a Java App within BlueStacks
Send data from Server to Client

It makes more sense for the computer to be the server because there will be multiple BlueStacks instances and I'd prefer to not have to "spawn" multiple programs / servers for what I'm doing.

Comment: Check the return values for `bind` and `listen`. Could be failing there. Maybe something on your computer has already grabbed port 54000.

Comment: And `accept()`, and `send()`. You should not close the socket, or call `WsaCleanup()` either, inside the reading loop. I don't know why you're printing `Can't initialize Winsock! Quitting` when the error comes from `getnameinfo()`.

Comment: Are you really claiming that this program runs right through without printing anything? If not, what *is* it printing? What *are* you claiming? And when you get an error, print the error, i.e. the value of `WSAGetLastError()`. Otherwise debugging is just a guessing game.

Comment: You should check whether any of these functions return an error code. Right now your program ignores the error code and pretends it succeeded. That's fine for a prototype, if the program is working, but it is not working so you should not be ignoring the operating system when it tries to tell you what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few mistakes in your socket code.

- not calling `WSACleanup()` if `WSAStartup()` is successful and then something goes wrong afterwards.
- not calling `closesocket()` if `socket()` is successful and then something goes wrong afterwards.
- not zeroing out the `sockaddr_in` that you pass to `bind()`.  Random bytes in the struct can cause `bind()` to fail.
- ignoring the return values of `bind()`, `listen()`, `accept()`, and `send()`.
- not treating the return value of `getnameinfo()` correctly.  It returns 0 on success, not failure.
- sending +1 extra byte back to the client than you received from the client.  If the client sends fewer bytes than your buffer can hold, that extra byte would be 0x00 due to your `ZeroMemory()` call.  But if the client actually sends enough bytes to completely fill your buffer, then you would send an extra byte from memory that you do not own.  If you really want to send a null terminator after everything you echo, do so explicitly.  Otherwise, a true echo server should only send back exactly what it receives, no more, no less.

Try something more like this:

```
void ServerStuff() {
    WSADATA WsData;
    int ret = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsData);
    if (ret != 0) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't initialize Winsock! Error: %d", ret);
        return;
    }

    //Create a socket
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't create a socket! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    //Bind the ip and port to a socket
    sockaddr_in hint = {};
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; //Could also use inet_pton

    ret = bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't bind socket! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    //Tell winsock the socket is for listening
    ret = listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);
    if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't listen on socket! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    //Wait for a connection
    sockaddr_in client = {};
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientSocket = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't accept a client! Error: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listening);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    char host[NI_MAXHOST] = {};  //Client's remote name

    ret = getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (ret != 0) {
        wxLogMessage("Can't get client name info! Error: %d", ret);
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client.sin_addr), host, NI_MAXHOST);
    }

    wxLogMessage("Client: %s, Connected on port: %hu", host, ntohs(client.sin_port));

    //Close listening socket - we don't need it anymore - later on we'll learn how to accept multiple client
    closesocket(listening);

    //while loop: accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];
    int bytesReceived;

    while (true)
    {
        //Wait for client to send data
        bytesReceived = recv(clientSocket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);

        if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            wxLogMessage("Can't read from client! Error: ", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        if (bytesReceived == 0) {
            wxLogMessage("Client Disconnected");
            break;
        }

        //Echo back to client
        ret = send(clientSocket, buf, bytesReceived, 0);
        if (ret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            wxLogMessage("Can't send to client! Error: ", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }
    }

    //Close the socket
    closesocket(clientSocket);

    //Cleanup winsock
    WSACleanup();

    wxLogMessage("Welp");
}
```

Comment: That solved it, thanks! I also needed to change Putty to Telnet mode and set it to Passive mode in order to get the echo working. Additionally I had to stop "using" std in order to get bind to work (I could've just been more explicit about where to get bind from but I figured this would be a good time to remove it from the code as it was causing trouble semi-frequently). I still have to implement a non-blocking and multi-client version but need to better understand Winsock beforehand. Putty should help me test. Thanks a ton! I really appreciate it.